# I have six siblings, but they say I'm the worst

Tags: riddle

*I have six siblings, but they say I'm the worst.*
*My entire family could kill you, but I was the first.*

*When you are with me, you're above all.*
*A bruised piper, I lead men and angels to their fall.*

**Who or what am I?**

Comment: Made me think of Monday :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> Pride

Because

> You are your 6 siblings are the seven deadly sins. If I remember correctly, Pride is the first.
>  The whole family could kill you = "Deadly".
>  A prideful person believes that they are above all other people.
>  A bruised piper and fallen angel could be references to the Devil.

Comment: You've got the answer. BTW, "a bruised piper" is an anagram for "pride superbia"; superbia being the latin name for pride.